# Nvidia graphic drivers slowing system

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed ubuntu 12.10 first, and tried for 2 days.... everything looks great and problem started after I installed graphic drivers. I installed "additional drivers" software from software manager, and installed recommended drivers from there. After that it started slowing down my system frequently. It works fine for some time when I restart, I dont know why and when it starts again but it makes very slow like i have to wait 2 min to open my firefox browser completely.

I formatted my  system(only Linux) then installed 12.04. I am getting same problem here also after  installing graphic card drivers.

my system config: 2GB RAM, core2duo processor 2.80GHz, 500GB, NVIDIA GE force 9600GT(512mb) graphic card. I am using dual boot mode with Windows8

What could be the problem?

thanks

Comment: Maybe your VGA is overheating?

Comment: windows 8 on other hand working like charm..... i can play even games like crysis  over there.....